# How do I setup a proper VPN for my friends to play LAN games AND give them internet access?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, vpn

I'm trying to setup a VPN on my local network, but everyone who connects to me DOES have access to my laptop but not to the internet or other devices on the network.

How can I properly configure my VPN on windows to work correctly (giving internet + access to all devices on my network to the remote pc)?

Or is there software on windows which makes creating a VPN server easier? or maybe a VMWare image linux vpn server? I can't find any of those!

My requirement is that my friends don't have to install additional software, they have to be able to connect with default windows stuff.

My OS is Windows 8 Standart edition (not pro or enterprise) OEM.
Most of my friends have also windows 8, some windows 7.

Extra info:

My device is DMZ'ed (Demilitarized Zone, [disabled NAT on my device so it's accessible on the WAN])

I can access files, websites and services on other devices on my network, and all devices can access file shares, website and all other services on my device

When enabling VPN everything works except the client is unable to get internet access or access to any device on my network, client has only access to my device.

Comment: (In general terms, you havn't specified your VPN solution), you need to do 2 things - (1) Push a default route across the VPN and (2) Masquerate/NAT/fix up routing for the clients.

Comment: You do understand they need internet access to connect this VPN of yours.  Neither windows 8 nor Windows 7 support native vpn

Comment: @Ramhound Is the vpn-server in Windows 7 and XP not native?? See [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/6f8fa874-07e0-4c6a-a5b6-22c50e858d3b/do-windows-7-have-vpn-server-build-in). And vpn-client has always been built in.

Comment: I mean tht they connect (i use windows incomming connection) and then they use htier internet to connect to my laptop, then they are connected to me, but their devices show that they have no internet, they can't load pages, etc, ut they can message me on my laptop. It's weird, I know.

Answer (score 3):

> They have their own internet connection but when they connect to me they can access only my laptop, no internet pages or other stuff

If your friends loose their own internet access after connecting via VPN to your computer they could change their settings, that when connecting with VPN, their `default gateway` is **not routed** over your connection.

Deselect `Use default gateway on remote network` in the `Advanced TCP/IP Settings`.

[image]

Comment: Loose (adv.) : Not fastened, restrained, or contained: loose bricks. ; Lose (v) : To be unsuccessful in retaining possession of; mislay: He's always losing his car keys.

Answer (score 0):

How are those users connecting to your laptop without an internet connection? I assume that they are all part of the same LAN.

Have you considered [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/using-ics-internet-connection-sharing) ?

Comment: They have their own internet connection but when they connect to me they can access only my laptop, no internet pages or other stuff